# Extract texture from Sketchup model

Tags: sketchup

Is it possible to pull a texture out of a Sketchup model? I have a model with me and I'd like to use an original texture from it, but I don't have the original.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **File -> Export -> 3D Model**. Export it as a **COLLADA File (*.dae)** file.

Click on the **Options** button and make sure that **Export Texture Maps** is checked.

Go to the exported file location. In the directory, there should be a folder with the exported file name (viz. housemodel if the filename is housemodel.dae), containing all of the textures.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Materials panel **Window > Default Tray > Materials**
2. Click on the Home icon to view the **In Model** materials collection, or select **In Model** from the Dropdown Menu.
3. **Right-click** on the texture you want > **Export Texture Image**.